Existence of a holomorphic function on a punctured plane
Does there exist a function $f$, holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$, such that
$$
|f(z)| \geq \frac{1}{|z|^{9 / 10}}
$$
for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ ? Prove your assertion.
My attempt:
From the inequality we can conclude that
$$ |f(z)| > 0 \quad \text{for $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$}$$
So $\frac{1}{f}$ is holomorphic and
$$\frac{1}{|f(z)|} \leq |z|^{9/10}$$
On the circle $|z| = R$, $\frac{1}{|f|} \leq R^{9/10}$ so in particular $\frac{1}{f}$ is bounded near 0 so it extends to a holomorphic function by Riemann Removable singularity theorem. Thus $\frac{1}{f}$ is entire and is bounded by $|z|^{9/10}$ so it must be a polynomial of degree at most $9/10$. Thus $\frac{1}{f}$ is identically constant. But $f(z) = c \in \mathbb{C}$ does not satisfy the initial inequality. So does that imply that such a function cannot exist?
I am really not sure whether this logic works. I also tried to use maximum modulus principle or minimum modulus principle but had no success since we do not know the value of $f$ on the boundary of the circle. I would appreciate any suggestions and advice.

Your argument is fine.

Your approach is good. When you reach the conclusion that $\frac1f$ extends to an entire function $\varphi\colon\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ such that $(\forall z\in\Bbb C):|\varphi(z)|\leqslant|z|^{9/10}$, you can apply Cauchy's inequalities and say that, for each $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and each $r>0$,$$\frac{|\varphi^{(n)}(0)|}{n!}\leqslant r^{-n}\sup_{|z|=r}|\varphi(z)|\leqslant r^{9/10-n}.$$Therefore,$$|\varphi^{(n)}(0)|\leqslant\lim_{r\to\infty}n!r^{9/10-n}=0.$$Since this occurs for each $n>0$, $\varphi$ is constant. And,since $\varphi(0)=0$, $\varphi$ is the null function. This cannot be true, since $z\ne0\implies\varphi(z)=\frac1{f(z)}$.
Like this, you avoid mentioning polynomials with degree $\frac9{10}$.
